# Call SQL stored procedure from Access

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba

I have a SQL Server stored procedure (`dbo.WiegenMain`) as below:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[WiegenMain]
AS 
BEGIN

    insert into dbo.wiegen (Tag, Aufträge_anzahl, Wiegeraum) 
      select 
         dbo.datepart2(BUCHUNG_BIS) as Tag, 
         count(distinct AUFTRAGSNUMMER), Kurztext as Wiegeraum 
      from 
         dbo.tblZEITERFASSUNG 
      inner join 
         dbo.tblBELEGUNGSEINHEIT on  tblZEITERFASSUNG.ID_BELEGUNGSEINHEIT = tblBELEGUNGSEINHEIT.ID 
      where 
         ID_BUCHUNGSART = 9 
         and ID_BELEGUNGSEINHEIT IN
             (SELECT ID_BELEGUNGSEINHEIT 
              FROM dbo.tblPROZESS_BELEGUNGSEINHEIT  
              WHERE ID_PROZESS = 3)
         and ABSCHLUSS = 1 
         AND dbo.DatePart2(BUCHUNG_BIS) = dbo.DatePart2(getdate())
     group by 
         dbo.DatePart2(BUCHUNG_BIS), Kurztext 
END
```

I want to call this stored procedure in Microsoft Access using VBA, I have tried the following :

First try:

```
Function InsertWiegen()

Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rcs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim strSQL As String
Dim strDel As String

Set conn = CurrentProject.Connection
strDel = "DELETE dbo.wiegen WHERE Tag = '" & Date & "'"
strSQL = "INSERT INTO dbo.wiegen ([Tag], [Aufträge_anzahl], [Wiegeraum]) " & _
         "SELECT dbo.DatePart2([BUCHUNG_BIS]) as [Tag], count(distinct [AUFTRAGSNUMMER]) as [Aufträge_anzahl], Kurztext as [Wiegeraum] from dbo.tblZEITERFASSUNG inner join dbo.tblBELEGUNGSEINHEIT on tblZEITERFASSUNG.ID_BELEGUNGSEINHEIT=tblBELEGUNGSEINHEIT.ID where ID_BUCHUNGSART=9 and ID_BELEGUNGSEINHEIT in (SELECT ID_BELEGUNGSEINHEIT FROM dbo.tblPROZESS_BELEGUNGSEINHEIT WHERE ID_PROZESS = 3) and [ABSCHLUSS]=1 AND dbo.DatePart2([BUCHUNG_BIS])= dbo.DatePart2('" & Date & "') group by dbo.DatePart2([BUCHUNG_BIS]), [Kurztext]"

Set rcs = conn.Execute(strDel)

conn.Execute (strSQL)

Set rcs = Nothing

conn.Close

Exit Function

End Function
```

Second Try:

```
Function InsertWiegen()

Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rcs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim strSQL As String
Dim strDel As String

Set conn = CurrentProject.Connection
'Set cmd.ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.Connection
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
cmd.CommandText = "WiegenMain"
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc

strDel = "DELETE dbo.wiegen WHERE Tag = '" & Date & "'"

Set rcs = conn.Execute(strDel)
cmd.Execute

Set rcs = Nothing
Set cmd = Nothing

conn.Close

Exit Function

End Function
```

dbo.datepart2() Function:

```
ALTER function [dbo].[DatePart2] (@date datetime)
returns datetime
as 
begin

return(cast(CONVERT(varchar(12), @date, 101) AS datetime))
end
```

Problem: Both the methods give the error -

> 'The conversion of a char datatype to a datetime datatype resulted in
>   an out-of-range datetime value.'

The stored procedure is working perfectly in SQL Server Management Studio, but raises error in Microsoft Access. The `strDel` is working fine, it deletes the records from the database table sucessfully, problem is with the strSQL query. I would really appreciate, if anyone can find out what is causing the problem..

Comment: Not the problem here, but you have an extra double quote in your SELECT statement in your 1st try, right before the GROUP BY statement.  I think the double quote right before the paren needs removed.

Comment: Thanks, I removed those, but still having the same problem..

Comment: Is BUCHUNG_BIS a datetime data type?

Comment: Yes its the datetime data type field

Comment: Do you have a sample of what is in your BUCHUNG_BIS field?  Your datepart2 function works with GetDate()

Comment: Yes, BUCHUNG_BIS has the value as '26.02.2013 17:00:06', datepart2 function works with GetDate()

Comment: Then it is your BUCHUNG_BIS value.  You probably need to convert it first to a valid datetime value.  For instance, if I convert that value to '02-26-2013 17:00:06', it works (but then I am in the U.S., so...)

Comment: But it is working in sql server management studio, do I need to change it to make it work in Access ?

Comment: I ran it in management studio as well, and I got the error you stated using your BUCHUNG_BIS value, but it worked fine for GetDate or when I changed BUCHUNG_BIS as I stated above.  It may be related to regional settings, but never having worked overseas, I am not sure.

Comment: Yes I believe its the regional settings. When I try other format for date values, it raises error in management studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem in another way:

```
strSQL = "INSERT INTO dbo.wiegen ([Tag], [Aufträge_anzahl], [Wiegeraum]) 
SELECT left([BUCHUNG_BIS],11) as [Tag], count(distinct [AUFTRAGSNUMMER]) as [Aufträge_anzahl], Kurztext as [Wiegeraum] 
from dbo.tblZEITERFASSUNG 
inner join
dbo.tblBELEGUNGSEINHEIT on tblZEITERFASSUNG.ID_BELEGUNGSEINHEIT=tblBELEGUNGSEINHEIT.ID 
where ID_BUCHUNGSART=9 and ID_BELEGUNGSEINHEIT 
in 
(SELECT ID_BELEGUNGSEINHEIT FROM dbo.tblPROZESS_BELEGUNGSEINHEIT WHERE ID_PROZESS = 3)
and [ABSCHLUSS]=1 AND left([BUCHUNG_BIS],11)= left(GETDATE(), 11) 
group by left([BUCHUNG_BIS],11), [Kurztext]"
```

Replaced my datepart2 function with left() function, now it executes successfully without any error.

Answer (score 0):

The text that you are inserting into your SQL statement for the Date will depend on your international settings. Try converting it to 'YYYY-MM-DD' like this:-

```
strDel = "DELETE dbo.wiegen WHERE Tag = '" & format (Date, "YYYY-MM-DD") & "'"
```

Comment: But strDel is working fine, it deletes the records from the table successfully, the problem is with the strSQL statement.. Thanks :)

Comment: Where is your datepart1 function?  You are using that in the SQL query, but above you have the datepart2 function.

Comment: datepart1 was having return type varchar, rest was same, I tried with datepart2 in Access, still it has the same error

Answer (score 0):

What data type is Tag in SQL?

If it is numeric then

strDel = "DELETE dbo.wiegen WHERE Tag = " & format (Date, "DD")

Comment: Tag is of datetime data type in SQL