# Call SQL function which requires datetime parameter from Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have the following (dbo.DatePart2()) SQL function:

```
ALTER function [dbo].[DatePart2] (@date datetime)
returns datetime
as 
begin

return(cast(CONVERT(varchar(12), @date, 101) AS datetime))
end
```

I need to call this function from Microsoft Access using VBA, and I tried the following:

```
Function InsertWiegen()

Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rcs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim strSQL As String
Dim strDel As String
Dim temp As String
Dim y As Date

Set conn = CurrentProject.Connection
temp = Format(Now(), "MM.dd.yyyy")
y = CStr(temp)

'strSQL = "INSERT INTO dbo.test ([a],[b]) SELECT * FROM dbo.test2 WHERE c = '" & y & "'"
'strSQL = "INSERT INTO dbo.test ([a], [b]) VALUES ('" & y & "', 3)"    

strSQL = "select dbo.DatePart2('" & temp & "')"
Debug.Print temp
Set rcs = conn.Execute(strSQL)
Set rcs = Nothing

conn.Close

Exit Function

End Function
```

Problem: It throws an error:

> 'The conversion of a char datatype to a datetime datatype resulted in
>   an out-of-range datetime value.'

The stored procedure is working perfectly in SQL Server Management Studio, but raises error in Microsoft Access.  I would really appreciate, if anyone can find out what is causing the problem..

Comment: My guess is that this could be due to the format `mm.dd.yyyy` that you are passing the date in. Change it to `yyyy/mm/dd` and see if it works. Also, why do you need to call SQL Server (from Access) to get the date without the time part?

Comment: Actually I have to insert into a sql table using this function from Access, and I don't require the time portion from one of the field of the table from where I have to pick the data..

Comment: Can you give an example of what data you need to pass from Access to SQL so that it gets inserted into SQL? Did you try the format change, I suggested above?

Comment: Yes I tried the format change you suggested, but it throws the same error. Example data: 26.02.2013 17:00:06, it is also from sql table with data type 'datetime'

Comment: possible duplicate of [Call SQL stored procedure from Access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18207924/call-sql-stored-procedure-from-access)

Comment: Yup, I simplified the previous problem to this problem. Anyway, its solved now, thank you all..

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem in another way:

```
strSQL = "INSERT INTO dbo.wiegen ([Tag], [Aufträge_anzahl], [Wiegeraum]) 
SELECT left([BUCHUNG_BIS],11) as [Tag], count(distinct [AUFTRAGSNUMMER]) as [Aufträge_anzahl], Kurztext as [Wiegeraum] 
from dbo.tblZEITERFASSUNG 
inner join
dbo.tblBELEGUNGSEINHEIT on tblZEITERFASSUNG.ID_BELEGUNGSEINHEIT=tblBELEGUNGSEINHEIT.ID 
where ID_BUCHUNGSART=9 and ID_BELEGUNGSEINHEIT 
in 
(SELECT ID_BELEGUNGSEINHEIT FROM dbo.tblPROZESS_BELEGUNGSEINHEIT WHERE ID_PROZESS = 3)
and [ABSCHLUSS]=1 AND left([BUCHUNG_BIS],11)= left(GETDATE(), 11) 
group by left([BUCHUNG_BIS],11), [Kurztext]"
```

Replaced my datepart2 function with sql inbuilt left() function, now it executes successfully without any error.